Setting a questionnaire form on Sharepoint
I'd like to develop a complex form on SharePoint that includes a description page explaining what this is about, followed by 30+ questions. Some questions need the user to attach documents (pdf, MS Excel, jpg, etc.). The link to this form will be shared with users so that they may fill out the details. When a user submits the form, it should be saved in a specific location in SharePoint. Is it possible to set this up with Power Automate?

Did you consider using Microsoft Form instead of SharePoint? Licensing is generally the same.

Yes, I did try MS Form, but it has lots of limitations.

SharePoint would have more limits in fact!

Yes, you can definitely set this up in SharePoint using Power Automate, and here’s a simple breakdown of how you can achieve this.

Create the Form on SharePoint

Start by creating a SharePoint list that will act as your form. You can use a SharePoint list or Microsoft Lists, depending on your environment.
Description Page: You can make the first column a multi-line text field to provide a description of the form. This way, users can understand what the form is about before filling out the questions.
Questions: Add each question as a separate column (Text fields, choice fields, date pickers, etc.). If a question requires document uploads, create a ‘File Upload’ column by enabling attachments in the list.

Sharing the Form

Once your SharePoint list (form) is ready, you can share a link to the list with users. You can customize the permissions so users can submit their responses without having full access to the rest of the list’s data.

Document Uploads

For questions that require users to attach files:
In your SharePoint list, ensure that the ‘Attachments’ feature is enabled (this is on by default for lists). Users will be able to upload files like PDFs, Excel sheets, images, etc.
Alternatively, you can create a separate document library for file uploads and link it to your form.

Using Power Automate to Save Form Responses

Here’s where Power Automate comes into play to handle automation once the user submits the form.

Trigger: Set up a flow that triggers when an item is created in the
SharePoint list (this is when a user submits the form).

Actions: In the flow, you can set specific actions to save the form
data, move    the uploaded files to another document library, or even
email the    user a confirmation.

Example: After a user submits a form, you can    use Power Automate
to copy the attachments to a dedicated document    library for better
organization. Step-by-Step Power Automate Flow

Example: Trigger: “When an item is created” (SharePoint trigger for
when someone submits a response in your list).

Check for Attachments: If users attach files, use the Get Attachments
action in Power Automate to retrieve them.

Save to Another Location: Use the Create File action to move the
attachments to a different document library, so they’re organized in
one spot.

Save Form Data: You can save all form data (questions and responses)
in a separate SharePoint list, another document library, or even send
the results via email to someone.

Notifications (optional): You can add an action to send a
confirmation email to the user or to notify someone (like a manager)
about the new submission.



Sounds like AI generated content.
